# Do not show error message on prestashop 1.7.1

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I found the ps.1.7.1 do not show any error message on the checkout page, e.g I login with wrong password, it will not show error message on that, e.g if I input the exists email to create a account, it will not show error. Or if there is any payment error, it still not show.

Anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. I'm fighting with it but no success. I would like to display error with an alert javascript when I click on "add to cart" button. It doesn't work. Before, with ps 1.6 or 1.5, I just needed to add something on $this->error[] on cartController function.

For warning, success, info displayed on templates after submited a form, it seems to be broken too.

Comment: ask question if you are facing problem answer should depict solution not problem itself